# My AuthContext works for a while, and shows the displayname, then i get this error once the page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Using Firebase 9:
When i comment out the user.displayname, no errors. When i uncomment, it will show the displayName in the Navbar, however when i refresh the page or click away i will get the following errors below

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'displayName')

````
src/components/Navbar.js:13
  10 | return (
  11 |   <nav>
  12 |     <h1>My Reading List</h1>
> 13 |     <p>{user.displayName}</p>
     | ^  14 |     <ul>
  15 |       <li>
  16 |         <Link to="/">Home</Link>
(anonymous function)
src/context/AuthContext.js:28
  25 | 
  26 | useEffect(() => {
  27 |   const unsub = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
> 28 |     dispatch({ type: "AUTH_IS_READY", payload: user });
     | ^  29 |     unsub();
  30 |   });
  31 | }, []);
 514 | _assert(promise, this, AuthErrorCode.INTERNAL_ERROR);
  515 | // The callback needs to be called asynchronously per the spec.
  516 | // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises
> 517 | promise.then(() => cb(this.currentUser));
      | ^  518 | 
  519 | if (typeof nextOrObserver === 'function') {
  520 |   return subscription.addObserver(nextOrObserver, error, completed)```
````

Comment: need some code to have a bit of context as to why it's not working....

Comment: How did you get the variable `user`?

Comment: If that `user` is Firebase auth's [`User`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user) which can be null, then you'll have to handle that yourself. It might be best if you share your code.

Comment: I destructed user from AuthContext,

const {user} = useAuthContext();

it works and shows, however upon any refresh or clicking any links that error still appears

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the error was coming due to authentication state in route guarding. When you apply route guarding, make sure you set your permissions correctly